# 検索フォームでユーザー名を入力しユーザーに紐づいた投稿を一覧画面に表示させたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

userモデルにはnameカラムはなくuserの保存が成功すればprofileの保存も成功するようになっています。
profileにnameカラムはあるのですがコントローラーで下記のように定義してもuserモデルにカラムがないので検索ができません。
ユーザー名でそのユーザーの投稿を検索するにはどのようにしたらよいかご教示いただきたいです。

```rb
posts_controller.rb

  def search
    @q = Post.ransack(params[:q])
    @posts = @q.result.includes(:users, :comments).order(created_at: :desc)
  end
```

```rb
_seaech.html.erb

<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :title_or_body_cont, id: "search_field_of_post", class: 'form-control me-2', placeholder: "投稿" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :comments_body_cont, id: "search_field_of_comment", class: 'form-control me-2', placeholder: "コメント" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :user_name_cont, id: "search_field_of_user", class: 'form-control me-2', placeholder: "ユーザー" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Search", class: 'btn btn-outline-success' %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

```rb
　　　  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.text "body", null: false
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end　

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_profiles_on_user_id"

(略）

　  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", null: false
    t.string "password_digest", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "posts", "users"
  add_foreign_key "profiles", "users"
```